# Having trouble understanding the complexities of HttpComponents re: preprocess, postprocess, executor etc

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to understand how Apache's HttpComponents works, but there are so many layers of complexity and classes.

I'm using one of the sample codes Apache provides (there are few others available online), [Basic HTTP GET](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html)

I particularly don't understand what is going on in these three lines, even when I look at the source code.

```
httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, coreContext);
HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, coreContext);
httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, coreContext);
```

Can someone with a clear understanding explain it?

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */

package org.apache.http.examples;

import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpCoreContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessorBuilder;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestExpectContinue;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestTargetHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Elemental example for executing multiple GET requests sequentially.
 */
public class ElementalHttpGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
            .add(new RequestContent())
            .add(new RequestTargetHost())
            .add(new RequestConnControl())
            .add(new RequestUserAgent("Test/1.1"))
            .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).build();

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

        HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
        coreContext.setTargetHost(host);

        DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
        ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;

        try {

            String[] targets = {
                    "/",
                    "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample",
                    "/somewhere%20in%20pampa"};

            for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket);
                }
                BasicHttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", targets[i]);
                System.out.println(">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri());

                httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, coreContext);
                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, coreContext);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, coreContext);

                System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                System.out.println("==============");
                if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, coreContext)) {
                    conn.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection kept alive...");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [Here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor.html#preProcess%28org.apache.http.HttpRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) is the javadoc explaining what an `HttpRequestExecutor` does.

Answer (score -1):

It is a fairly common chain of responsibility patter whereby each protocol interceptors enforces one particular aspect of the HTTP protocol for all outgoing and incoming messages.